# safewithdrawal on contracts not work with goal not met?

Tags: contract-debugging

I created a crowdsale contract and sent ethereum to it to test it. The contract was supposed to last for 3 months and then end at which point I thought all the eth would be returned to anyone who sent it if the goal was not met. The funds have not been returned and the safe withdraw function does not work from my owner account. What is going on here? I have 2 contracts like this for two different coins I created. I donated eth to those to get my coin kicked back to my wallet which worked. But now I want my eth back from the crowd sale contract yet I have no idea what to do..